# Dice Probability from Eldritch Horror!

Tags: probability, statistics

1. How to calculate the probability of getting a minimum of one 5-die or one 6-die by rolling 3 dice at once?
2. And, is it mathematically correct that further adding 1 die into the dice pool has a diminishing return?

PS: These questions perplex me; and they stem from playing "Eldritch Horror" board game!

Comment: Do you mean: if you roll 3 die, what is the probability that at least one die shows a 5 or a 6?

Comment: Yes!  And, thanks for your attention..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of a dice not showing 5 or 6 is $\frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3}$. Therefore the probability of not having any of the dice showing 5 of 6 is $\frac{2}{3}^3$. So the probabiliity of at least one die showing 5 or 6 is $1 - \frac{2}{3}^3$.

For $n$ dice this probability generalises to $1 - \frac{2}{3}^n$. The more dice you have, the larger this probability.

Comment: That makes great sense..  Using your equation, I can work out various probabilities at a given n..  So, it seems the diminishing return holds true - the higher n, the less increase in probability..

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I initially misunderstood the question and answered a different question. I left my old answer below for reference.

**New answer:**

The probability of getting at least one ($j \geq 1$) face with a value $k$ or higher when we roll $n$ dices with $f$ faces numbered $1,2,\ldots,f$ is given by the cumulative binomial distribution.

This case can computed directly because it is the complementary of getting zero successes.

$$
P(j \geq 1) = 1 - P(j = 0) = 1 - \left( \frac{k - 1}{f} \right) ^n
$$

In this specific case, $f=6$, $k=5$ and $n=3$, so we get [bitesizebo's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3202932/649368):
$$
P(j \geq 1, n=3) = 1 - \left( \frac{5 - 1}{6} \right) ^3 = 1 - \left( \frac{4}{6} \right) ^3 = 0.7037
$$

If we rolled $n=4$ dice the probability would become higher:
$$
P(j \geq 1, n=4) = 1 - \left( \frac{5 - 1}{6} \right) ^4 = 1 - \left( \frac{4}{6} \right) ^4 = 0.8025
$$

---

**Old answer** Note that this does not provides an answer to the original question.

The probability of rolling $n$ dice with $f$ faces numbered $1,2,\ldots,f$ and all of them being at least $k \in \{ 1,2,\ldots,f \}$ is:
$$
P(m \geq k) = \left( \frac{f - k + 1}{f} \right) ^n
$$

If the minimum $m$ is $k$ it means that all the dice had at least $k$ but not all of them had at least $k+1$, so:
$$
P(m = k) = P(m \geq k) - P(m \geq k + 1)  = \left( \frac{f - k + 1}{f} \right) ^n - \left( \frac{f - k}{f} \right) ^n
$$

---

By the way, the maximum $M$ has similar (and perhaps more straight forward) formulas:

$$
P(M \leq k) = \left( \frac{k}{f} \right) ^n
$$

And
$$
P(M = k) = P(M \leq k) - P(M \leq k - 1)  = \left( \frac{k}{f} \right) ^n - \left( \frac{k - 1}{f} \right) ^n
$$

---

So, for instance, for rolling $n=3$ dice with $f=6$ faces, the probability of the minimum being at least $m=5$ is:

$$
P(m = 5) = \left( \frac{6 - 5 + 1}{6} \right) ^3 - \left( \frac{6 - 5}{6} \right) ^3 \\
P(m = 5) = \frac{7}{216} = 0.03241
$$

While if we rolled $n=4$ dice the probability would be smaller:
$$
P(m = 5) = \left( \frac{6 - 5 + 1}{6} \right) ^4 - \left( \frac{6 - 5}{6} \right) ^4 \\
P(m = 5) = \frac{15}{1296} = 0.1157
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response..  Though your equations address a different kind of problem, they indeed give me good perspective..

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought that the dice with the smallest number was $5$ or $6$. From your comment I got that you wanted instead that at least $1$ out of the $3$ dice was a $5%$ or a $6$.

Comment: @GaranSebastianBach I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Superb!  Yes, it truly is a binomial distribution.. How could I forget it!  Thanks for the enlightenment..